# Дублирование страниц в yii

Tags: yii

Ниже приведены примеры, при которых фреймверк yii выдает одну и туже страницу. Нужный вариант пометил как "верный!", как избавиться от остальных?

```
http://site.ru/site/index
http://site.ru/site
http://site.ru/  - верный!
```

И вот еще пример контроллера:

```
http://site.ru/oplata/index
http://site.ru/oplata  - верный!
```

Comment: Если ради поисковиков, то как вариант - rel="canonical" генерить нужный.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, в .htaccess прописать RewriteRule с редиректом.